# Where do I place a reset stack function in navigator?

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I am working for the first time in React Native and trying to reset the stack navigation whenever a user clicks to a different screen.  I've created a resetStack function above all the navigators but cannot figure out where to call it for it to work, I've been shooting in the dark for a while now so any input is appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

I've tried a few different places.  In the navigationOptions, below that, in the Navigator that puts them all together.  I can share more code if it's necessary.

```
resetStack = () =>{
  this.props.navigation
  .dispatch(StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: Home
```

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({

  Home: HomeScreen,
})

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarOptions: {
    labelStyle: {
      fontSize: 7,
    },  
    showIcon: true,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: Colors.starsBlue,
    },
    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
    }
  },
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? 'ios-home'
          : 'md-home'
      }
    />

  ),
}
```

Comment: Reset stack function used where you want to reset navigation stack. For example at the time of sign in or logout when user logout or sign in user come for various screen but at the end they came to home screen or login screen. they back press from home if at this stage we are not reset stack all navigating screen come again. that's why we used reset stack function.

Answer (score 0):

I have Checked the solution you tried .
Try replacing

```
onPress={() => { this.handleHomePressed() }}
```

With

```
 onPress={() =>this.handleHomePressed() }
```

inside handleHomePressed():

```
handleHomePressed(){
    return this.props
               .navigation
               .dispatch(NavigationActions.reset(
                 {
                    index: 0,
                    actions: [
                      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home'})
                    ]
                  }));
  }
```

Hope it works !

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.  You are asking me to replace an onPress with a different one but I don't have an onPress function to begin with?